# How to get the direction (angle) of rectangle after rotating it from a pivot point

Tags: trigonometry, javafx-2

I normally just use setRotate(double value) and getRotate() when rotating a rectangle from its center. Suppose a rectangle is facing North if the getRotate() is 0 and I'm trying to get its direction, I simply get the negative of the getRotate() and get its remainder from 360 (if it's negative, I add 360). Which means that an angle of 0 degrees faces North, and rotating it clockwise by a degree makes it 359 degrees (likewise, rotating it counter-clockwise by a degree makes it 1 degree).

```
    public double angle(){
        double angle = -rectangle.getRotate();
        if(angle<0){ angle += 360; }
        return angle%360;
    }
```

However, my problem now is that I need to rotate the rectangle not from its center but from a pivot point. I can't use setRotate(double value) and getRotate() anymore so I have to use getTransforms().add(new Rotate(double angle, double pivotX, double pivotY)).

Now, my problem is that I want to know the angle of the direction where the rectangle faces but I can no longer use getRotate(). And even if I use the getAngle() from the Rotate,  I still don't know how to get the direction it faces because it wasn't rotated from the center.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have only one rotate transform for your rectangle you can just get info from transform:

```
for (Transform transform : rectangle.getTransforms()) {
    if (transform instanceof Rotate) {
        return ((Rotate)transform).getAngle();
    }
}
```