# How can I get the direction of rotation relative to a given point from the mouse movement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, rotation, trigonometry

I'm using the following functions to track mouse movement and rotate an object:

```
function getAngle(dx, dy) {
    var angle
    if (dx != 0) {
        var radians = Math.atan(dy / dx) + (dx < 0 ? Math.PI : 0)
        angle = radiansToDegrees(radians);
        if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
    } else {
        angle = dy > 0 ? 90 : 270;
    }
    return angle;
}

function getAngleBetweenPoints(p1, p2) {
    var dx = p1.x - p2.x
    var dy = p1.y - p2.y
    return getAngle(dx, dy)
}

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    if (selectionBounds) {
        var midpoint = new pe.Classes.Point(selectionBounds.Left + (selectionBounds.Width / 2), selectionBounds.Top + (selectionBounds.Height / 2));
        var mousepoint = new pe.Classes.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
        var angle = getAngleBetweenPoints(midpoint, mousepoint);
        if (lastAngle) {
            var diff = angle - lastAngle;
            rotate(degreesToRadians(diff));
        }
        lastAngle = angle;
    }
});
```

This works well, as long as I move the mouse slowly, and as long as the mouse doesn't get too close to the origin (midpoint). Moving too quickly causes additional spin rotations, and coming close to the origin causes unexpected changes of direction.

How can I fix this code? I really just need to know which direction the mouse is moving in (clockwise or anti-clockwise), as I can get an idea of the speed just from the change in mousepoint and then update the rotation based on that.

There are literally dozens of SO threads on topics related to this ([How to get the direction (angle) of rectangle after rotating it from a pivot point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798743/how-to-get-the-direction-angle-of-rectangle-after-rotating-it-from-a-pivot-poi), [How to get cardinal mouse direction from mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689397/how-to-get-cardinal-mouse-direction-from-mouse-coordinates), [Moving a rotated element in the direction of the rotation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779745/moving-a-rotated-element-in-the-direction-of-the-rotation-in-javascript)) - but I haven't been able to find anything that can answer this question, except one comment referring to this requiring the cross product, which I didn't fully understand.

Comment: You can use `Math.atan2(dy, dx)` to get the angle for `dy / dx` directly mapped into the right quadrant.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more? How should it be different from what I've got already: `var radians = Math.atan(dy / dx) + (dx < 0 ? Math.PI : 0)`

Comment: I haven't checked yours for accuracy, it's simply that `Math.atan2` is designed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Actually I think your implementation is incorrect.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2

Comment: Why are you rotating by the difference instead of setting the rotation angle?

Comment: I've implemented something similar to the functionality I believe you're looking for here: http://jsfiddle.net/8VSUB/2/ Is this not what you're asking for? (note it will only work in webkit browsers atm as I only used "webkitRequestAnimationFrame").

Comment: Also I would recommend against repeatedly converting back and forth between Degrees and Radians. If you need a Degree value for display, convert it only then, but you should do all of your calculations in radians.

Comment: @Shmiddty - I'm looking for the delta angle because I have several objects to rotate, any of which may or may not already have been rotated. The simplest thing to do is to increment their rotation by the delta. I'll take a look at your example in the morning, but I really just want to know reliably if the mouse is moving clockwise, or anti-clockwise, relative to a central point. As a bonus, it's useful for me to know how fast it is travelling, but this latter value can be quite imprecise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wRexz/3/ (click and drag to rotate the rectangle)

```
    var angle = 0, sp = startpoint, mp = midpoint;
    var p = {x:e.offsetX, y:e.offsetY};
    var sAngle = Math.atan2((sp.y-mp.y),(sp.x - mp.x));
    var pAngle = Math.atan2((p.y-mp.y),(p.x - mp.x));        

    angle = (pAngle - sAngle) * 180/Math.PI;

    $("#display").text(angle);
    $('#rotateme').css({ rotate: '+=' + angle });

    startpoint = {x:p.x, y:p.y};
```

The concept here is basic trig. You find the angle from 0 of the "start point" and do the same for the "end point" or "current point". Subtract the first from the second, and that is your "delta angle".

You will still get erratic behavior around the midpoint, due to the nature of how rapidly the angles can change. One solution to this is stopping rotation when within a certain distance of the midpoint.

Comment: And here's the same thing with a cuddly little kitten: http://jsfiddle.net/wRexz/4/

Comment: Yes, that works great. 'Basic trig' is (obviously) not my strong point, so many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @JcFx I find that drawing a diagram is immensely helpful for these kinds of things.